# InStr always returns zero

Tags: vba, excel

Any idea why the InStr formula below would always return zero even though the value in column C includes the word UNIT (e.g BETA UNIT)?

```
For k = 2 To y

wsFile.Range("P" & k).Value = InStr(Range("C" & k).Value, " UNIT")

Next k
```

I already switched .Value to .Text but that did not solve it.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Didn't qualify the `range`?

Comment: There is a space in `" UNIT"` should it be without the space `"UNIT"`?

Comment: @findwindow what do you mean by "Didn't qualify the range"?

Comment: @ScottCraner The space before UNIT is there purposely to avoid picking up values like SUNIT.

Comment: Could potentially be some sort of Unicode vs. ascii issue if the values in Column C were pasted from a website or something. When I evaluate `InStr(Range("C" & k).Value, " UNIT")` for a cell that contains "BETA UNIT" I get the expected return of 5, so there is nothing wrong with the way you are using `InStr`

Comment: @JohnColeman How would I go about identifying an issue like that? The data has been pulled from a database.

Comment: @findwindow was probably noticing the you have `wsFile` before `Range` on the LHS but not on the RHS. Perhaps you are looking at Column C in the wrong worksheet.

Comment: `what do you mean by "Didn't qualify the range"?` Sigh. So you don't even know what`wsFile.Range(` is doing XD

Comment: Maybe look at this: http://dailydoseofexcel.com/archives/2010/11/19/unicode-and-vbas-chrw-and-ascw-functions/ but my hunch is that @findwindow 's guess is probably a more likely explanation than some sort of encoding problem. Since I can't reproduce your problem we have nothing but guesswork to go on.

Comment: @findwindow The sigh is a bit uncalled for. It is just as likely that he wasn't aware of that usage of the word "qualify".

Comment: @JohnColeman that was exactly the issue. wsFile.Range("C" & k).Value fixed it. Such a rookie mistake.

Comment: Point take. I apologize.

Comment: Thanks everyone for your help!

Comment: @findwindow No offense taken!

Comment: Good. If @findwindow answers it you should accept it.

Comment: @findwindow dude, where's your [codereview.se] account? :D

Comment: @Mat'sMug lol I am not _that_ good.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the INSTR return values, hope it helps... [Return_Values](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w716i.png)